# How to remove paste overlay in Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

Microsoft Office programs turn worse each new version.

How to remove paste overlay which appears after paste in some random place and interfere working?

[image]

I want to paste some text at each line and after I pasted in in line 14, paste overlay appears over line 15, hiding the place I want to paste text into.

How to disable this "feature"?

The only way to hide overlay I found is to type something somewhere. But I don't want to do it. I want click mouse then press Ctrl-V, then click mouse again, then press Ctrl-V and so on. I don't want to interleave this with typing some garbage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the File tab > Options > Advanced. Scroll down to the "Cut, copy, and paste" section and untick the box for "Show Paste Options when content is pasted"

[image]